# Rails how to get associated model's attribute using `read_attribute`

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
@results.each do |result|
  pp result.driver.name                   # work
  pp result.read_attribute('driver_name') # nil
  pp result.read_attribute(:driver_name)  # nil
end
```

Are there any means by which we can `read_attribute` as shown above?

Comment: Why do you think that you can access with 'driver_name' the drivers name ? Is it possible to concat object access with underscore ??

Comment: read_attribute returns the value of attribute, what's wrong with the code above? it is returning nil since `result` doesn't have an attribute `driver_name` or does it?

Comment: @SimonFranzen In fact, I just want to write an example to "say" what I want. My English too bad... So how to read a value from an object by a string like that, dynamically.

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon yes, the `driver` is belong to the driver table. So have some way can read the value(driver.name)?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do that anyway, you can use `delegate` in your `results` model like:

```
delegate :name, to: :driver, prefix: true
```

Now try calling it, it should return name of the associated driver.

```
result.driver_name
```

Comment: @Duanckham do not apologize again and again about your bad english :) Learning by doing !

Comment: @Duanckham not necessarily the only way, but that's what I can think of it at the moment..let me know if you get any error..